# how to use a static char

Tags: c++

I am currently working with a *wxWidgets* project where I have to copy a *wxString* to a static c string that can hold the value for the life time of the program. Essentially my headerfile and source file look like this:

```
*****************PortDialog.h*****************

...
static char *portName; 

-----------------------end
```

and the source file is;

```
***************PortDialog.cpp*****************

.
.
. 
wxString str = "COM1"; 

strcpy(portName, (const char*)str.mbc_str()); 

---------------------end
```

However I run into the following linking error.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static char * portDialog::eportName" (?portName@portDialog@@2PADA)
```

Can somebody explain to me what is the mistake I am making here? Is it correct to use `static char *` for the said purpose?

Answer (score 0):

static variables declared in header should be initialized in cpp file see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr038.htm

Answer (score 0):

Besides the explanations you have received regarding the linker error, you should also be aware that you cannot call `strcpy` with the destination as a `char *` which has not been allocated memory to hold the source string.  It would compile (and link) but could do just about anything during run-time.

Answer (score 0):

static Variables should be declared in the cpp file

```
char* PortDialog::PortName = NULL;
```

Like u do to access methods(functions) of a class using Scope Resolution Operator

```
void PortDialog::SomeFunction()
{
  //Code Goes here
}
```